# Forma correcta de Excepción múltiple en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, excepciones

Planteo un problema en Python 3 donde en cada operación que realizó puede darse una excepción, algo como esto:

```
num = 12
a_num = 0
b_num = 1
c_num = 0
try:
    a = num/a_num
except Exception as ex:
    a = 0
try:
    b = num/b_num
except Exception as ex:
    b = 0
try:
    c = num/c_num
except Exception as ex:
    c = 0
    
print(a)
print(b)
print(c)
```

De esta forma obtengo el resultado correcto, pero podría plantearlo solo realizando un try except y conseguir el mismo resultado? Ya que dentro del mismo try except si se da el error los siguientes cálculos no se realizarán.

Comment: Para este caso en particular, creo que sería más sencillo si colocas if() que el denominador no sea cero antes de dividir.

Comment: `a = num/a_num if a_num else 0` y así con los otros

Comment: incluso `a,b,c = (num/x if x else 0 for x in (a_num, b_num, c_num))`

Comment: Ok, y sin utilizar if, con try exception hay opción o deberías realizar tantos try exception como operaciones?

Comment: Puedes escribir una función que haga la operación y retorne 0 si hubo excepción. Así solo escribes un `try/except` (dentro de esa función). Luego llamas a esa función 3 veces, ya sea en 3 líneas o en un bucle como `a,b,c = (dividir(num,x) for x in (a_num, b_num, c_num))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expandiendo un poco lo que menciono en el comentario, la forma de no repetir código suele ser extraerlo a una función, y llamarla en bucle si es posible. En este caso:

```
def dividir(numerador, denominador):
  try:
     return numerador/denominador
  except:
     return 0
```

Ahora el programa principal sería simplemente:

```
num = 12
a_num = 0
b_num = 1
c_num = 0
a = dividir(num, num_a)
b = dividir(num, num_b)
c = dividir(num, num_c)
```

O, en forma de bucle (mejor dicho, expresión generadora):

```
a, b, c = (dividir(num, x) for x in (a_num, b_num, c_num))
```

Answer (score 2):

Una alternativa simple es preguntar si el divisor es distinto de cero antes de hacer la división. Esto evita la generación de excepción y resulta más corto de escribir.

Aquí nos conviene ocupar el operador ternario

```
a if b else c
```

El resultado de esta expresión es `a` si `b` es verdadero, o `c`, si no lo es. `a, b, c` son expresiones Python válidas.

Con esto podemos chequear el divisor y calcular el valor en una sola línea:

```
num = 12
a_num = 0
b_num = 1
c_num = 0

a = num / a_num if a_num else 0
b = num / b_num if b_num else 0
c = num / c_num if c_num else 0

print(a)
print(b)
print(c)
```

produce:

```
0
12.0
0

Process finished with exit code 0
```